# Grunt build not including bower components in dist folder

Tags: gruntjs, bower, grunt-usemin

I'm learning how to use Grunt for build automation, tests, bower dependencies, etc.  I can't get the build task to include bower dependencies, and can't figure out why.  From what I've read, all I need to do is include comment blocks with build:css or js and the useminprepare task will concat and build it to the dist.  It doesn't.  What am I doing wrong?  I used webapp as the generator for yeoman.

header.php

```
<!-- bower:css -->
<!-- build:css styles/slidebars.min.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/slidebars/distribution/0.10.2/slidebars.min.css" />
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<!-- build:js scripts/jquery.js -->
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:js scripts/modernizr.js -->
<script src="../bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:js scripts/slidebars.min.js -->
<script src="../bower_components/slidebars/distribution/0.10.2/slidebars.min.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- build:css styles/css.css -->
<link href="styles/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:js scripts/slidebarsinit.js -->
<script defer="defer" src="scripts/slidebarsinit.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

gruntfile.js

```
// Generated on 2014-08-07 using generator-webapp 0.4.9
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // Load grunt tasks automatically
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    // Configurable paths
    var config = {
        app: 'app',
        dist: 'dist'
    };

    // Define the configuration for all the tasks
    grunt.initConfig({

        // Project settings
        config: config,

        php: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                    hostname: '127.0.0.1',
                    port: 5000,
                    base: 'app/'
                }
            },
            testphp: {
              options: {
                keepalive: true,
                open: true
              }
            }
        },

        // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
        watch: {
          markup: {
                files: ['index.php'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true,
                }
            },
            bower: {
                files: ['bower.json'],
                tasks: ['bowerInstall']
            },
            js: {
                files: ['<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
                tasks: ['jshint'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            jstest: {
                files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
                tasks: ['test:watch']
            },
            gruntfile: {
                files: ['Gruntfile.js']
            },
            sass: {
                files: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['sass:server', 'autoprefixer']
            },
            styles: {
                files: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
                tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
                },
                files: [
                    '<%= config.app %>/{,*/}*.{html,php}',
                    '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= config.app %>/images/{,*/}*'
                ]
            }
        },

        // The actual grunt server settings
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                open: true,
                livereload: 35729,
                // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
                hostname: 'localhost'
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    middleware: function(connect) {
                        return [
                            connect.static('.tmp'),
                            connect().use('/bower_components', connect.static('./bower_components')),
                            connect.static(config.app)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            test: {
                options: {
                    open: false,
                    //port: 9001,
                    middleware: function(connect) {
                        return [
                            connect.static('.tmp'),
                            connect.static('test'),
                            connect().use('/bower_components', connect.static('./bower_components')),
                            connect.static(config.app)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    base: '<%= config.dist %>',
                    livereload: false
                }
            }
        },

        // Empties folders to start fresh
        clean: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    dot: true,
                    src: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/*',
                        '!<%= config.dist %>/.git*'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            server: '.tmp'
        },

        // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
                reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
            },
            all: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
                '<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '!<%= config.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
                'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
            ]
        },

        // Mocha testing framework configuration options
        mocha: {
            all: {
                options: {
                    run: true,
                    //urls: ['http://<%= connect.test.options.hostname %>:<%= connect.test.options.port %>/index.html']
                    urls: ['http://<%= php.dev.options.hostname %>:<%= php.dev.options.port %>/index.php']
                }
            }
        },

        // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
        sass: {
            options: {
                includePaths: [
                    'bower_components'
                ]
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
                    src: ['*.scss'],
                    dest: '.tmp/styles',
                    ext: '.css'
                }]
            },
            server: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
                    src: ['*.scss'],
                    dest: '.tmp/styles',
                    ext: '.css'
                }]
            }
        },

        // Add vendor prefixed styles
        autoprefixer: {
            options: {
                browsers: ['last 1 version']
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                    src: '{,*/}*.css',
                    dest: '.tmp/styles/'
                }]
            }
        },

        // Automatically inject Bower components into the HTML file
        bowerInstall: {
            app: {
                //src: ['<%= config.app %>/index.html'],
                src: ['<%= config.app %>/header.php'],
                //exclude: ['bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js']
            },
            sass: {
                src: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}']
            }
        },

        // Renames files for browser caching purposes
        rev: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    src: [
                        '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.*',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/*.{ico,png}'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },

        // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
        // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
        // additional tasks can operate on them
        useminPrepare: {
            options: {
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
            },
            //html: '<%= config.app %>/index.html'
            html: '<%= config.app %>/header.php'
        },

        // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
        usemin: {
            options: {
                assetsDirs: ['<%= config.dist %>', '<%= config.dist %>/images']
            },
            //html: ['<%= config.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
            html: ['<%= config.dist %>/{,*/}*.php'],
            css: ['<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
        },

        // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
        imagemin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png}',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },

        svgmin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },

        htmlmin: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                    collapseWhitespace: true,
                    removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                    removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                    removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                    removeOptionalTags: true,
                    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                    useShortDoctype: true
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.dist %>',
                    //src: '{,*/}*.html',
                    src: '{,*/}*.php',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
                }]
            }
        },

        // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
        // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
        // to use the Usemin blocks.
        // cssmin: {
        //     dist: {
        //         files: {
        //             '<%= config.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
        //                 '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
        //                 '<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
        //             ]
        //         }
        //     }
        // },
        // uglify: {
        //     dist: {
        //         files: {
        //             '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
        //                 '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
        //             ]
        //         }
        //     }
        // },
        // concat: {
        //     dist: {}
        // },

        // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.app %>',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>',
                    src: [
                        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                        '.htaccess',
                        'images/{,*/}*.webp',
                        '{,*/}*.php',
                        //'{,*/}*.html',
                        //'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
                        'styles/{,*/}*.*',
                        'scripts/{,*/}*.*'
                    ]
                }, {
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '.',
                    //src: ['bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/fonts/bootstrap/*.*'],
                    src: ['bower_components/*.*'],
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
                }]
            },
            styles: {
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css'
            }
        },

        // Generates a custom Modernizr build that includes only the tests you
        // reference in your app
        modernizr: {
            dist: {
                devFile: 'bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
                outputFile: '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/vendor/modernizr.js',
                files: {
                    src: [
                        '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                        '!<%= config.dist %>/scripts/vendor/*'
                    ]
                },
                uglify: true
            }
        },

        // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up build process
        concurrent: {
            server: [
                'sass:server',
                'copy:styles'
            ],
            test: [
                'copy:styles'
            ],
            dist: [
                //'sass',
                'copy:styles',
                'imagemin',
                'svgmin'
            ]
        }
    });


    grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
            return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'concurrent:server',
            'autoprefixer',
            'connect:livereload',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
        grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
        grunt.task.run([target ? ('serve:' + target) : 'serve']);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('test', function (target) {
        if (target !== 'watch') {
            grunt.task.run([
                'clean:server',
                'concurrent:test',
                'autoprefixer'
            ]);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            //'connect:test',
            'mocha'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        //'useminPrepare',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'autoprefixer',
        //'concat',
        //'cssmin',
        //'uglify',
        'copy:dist',
        'useminPrepare',
        'modernizr',
        'rev',
        'usemin',
        'htmlmin'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'newer:jshint',
        'test',
        'build'
    ]);
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-php');                   
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['php:dev', 'watch']);
    grunt.registerTask('testphp', ['php:dev', 'test']);
};
```

useminPrepare output

```
$ grunt useminPrepare
Running "useminPrepare:html" (useminPrepare) task
Going through app/header.php to update the config
Looking for build script HTML comment blocks

Configuration is now:

  concat:
  { generated:
   { files:
      [ { dest: '.tmp\\concat\\styles\\slidebars.min.css',
          src: [ 'bower_components\\slidebars\\distribution\\0.10.2\\slidebars.m
in.css' ] },
        { dest: '.tmp\\concat\\scripts\\jquery.js',
          src: [ 'bower_components\\jquery\\dist\\jquery.js' ] },
        { dest: '.tmp\\concat\\scripts\\modernizr.js',
          src: [ 'bower_components\\modernizr\\modernizr.js' ] },
        { dest: '.tmp\\concat\\scripts\\slidebars.min.js',
          src: [ 'bower_components\\slidebars\\distribution\\0.10.2\\slidebars.m
in.js' ] },
        { dest: '.tmp\\concat\\styles\\css.css',
          src: [ 'app\\styles\\css.css' ] },
        { dest: '.tmp\\concat\\scripts\\slidebarsinit.js',
          src: [ 'app\\scripts\\slidebarsinit.js' ] } ] } }

  uglify:
  { generated:
   { files:
      [ { dest: 'dist\\scripts\\jquery.js',
          src: [ '.tmp\\concat\\scripts\\jquery.js' ] },
        { dest: 'dist\\scripts\\modernizr.js',
          src: [ '.tmp\\concat\\scripts\\modernizr.js' ] },
        { dest: 'dist\\scripts\\slidebars.min.js',
          src: [ '.tmp\\concat\\scripts\\slidebars.min.js' ] },
        { dest: 'dist\\scripts\\slidebarsinit.js',
          src: [ '.tmp\\concat\\scripts\\slidebarsinit.js' ] } ] } }

  cssmin:
  { generated:
   { files:
      [ { dest: 'dist\\styles\\slidebars.min.css',
          src: [ '.tmp\\concat\\styles\\slidebars.min.css' ] },
        { dest: 'dist\\styles\\css.css',
          src: [ '.tmp\\concat\\styles\\css.css' ] } ] } }

Done, without errors.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot I had asked this question.  For some reason I had commented out the concat, uglify, and cssmin tasks there in the build task because at first they were causing problems at first.  I uncommented them and it ran fine.